# 16.04: Keyboard & touchpad unresponsive. Also occurs with external USB keyboard & mouse.. Works OK w/ 18.04

Tags: software-installation

When I install Ubuntu 16 on Lenovo Ideapad s145, keyboard and touchpad doesn't work. Also I pluged in keyboard and mouse via usb, and again same problem. When booting Bootable USB drive, I get this error:

```
AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[4] not in IVRS table
AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[5] not in IVRS table
AMD-Vi: No southbridge IOAPIC found
AMD-Vi: Disabling interrupt remapping
cpu 0, invalid threshold interrupt offset 1 for bank 4, block 0
```

But I can install system normally, but on every boot mouse, touchpad and keyboard doesn't work

Laptop is brand new, I just unboxed it. I also tried Ubuntu 18 and Windows 10, and it is working...

Spec:

```
Amd a4 9125
4gb ddr4
256gb ssd
```

I can't post a photo of problem cause I just registered on forum...

Here is the image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aQ6b.jpg

Comment: Nikola, instead of a picture of the error, please select and copy the error text from the Terminal window, then return here, click [edit], and paste the text into the question. If you have a picture from a GUI app to show us, please upload the picture to a public image hosting site such as http://imgur.com , collect the URL for that uploaded image, and add that URL into the question, again using [edit].

Comment: Nikola, for a test, please download  a 'flavour' of 16.04 with a different Desktop from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours and check it for download errors following https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 . Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on a Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 .then boot with that 'flavour' and report the results.